# Find number of nonnegative integer solutions to x+3y+3z=n, given n, using generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> For every $n,x,y,z\in \mathbb N$, where $x\ge{0}$ and $y,z \ge1$
>
> Find the number of nonnegative integer solutions for
>   $x+3y+3z = n$

I created a generating function for the problem:

$(1+x+x^2+...)(x^3+x^6+x^9+...)^2$

$(1+x+x^2+...)x^6(1+x^3+x^6+...)^2$

$\frac{1}{1-x} \frac{x^6}{(1-x^3)^2}$
$= \frac{x^6}{(1-x)(1-x^3)^2}$

I can try breaking this expression into partial functions and try to find the coefficient of $x^n$ from there, but I get stuck in that stage.

can you please help me complete this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Call your variables $a_i$, so that you want $a_1 + 3 a_2 + 3 a_3 = n$ with $a_i \ge 0$ integers.

The values of $a_1$ are represented by:

$$
1 + z + z^2 + \dotsb = \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$

The values added by $a_2$ and $a_3$ are:

$$
z^3 + z^6 + \dotsb = \frac{z^3}{1 - z^3}
$$

In all, you want the coeficient of $z^n$ in:

$\begin{align}
[z^n] \frac{z^6}{(1 - z) (1 - z^3)^2}
  &= [z^{n - 6}]
       \left(
          \frac{1}{9 (1 - z)^3}
            + \frac{2}{9 (1 - z)^2}
            + \frac{7}{27 (1 - z)}
            + \frac{1 + 2 z}{(1 + z + z^2)^2}
            + \frac{8 + 7 z}{1 + z + z^2}
       \right)
\end{align}$

The last two terms are troublesome. We can factor more using complex numbers, using the cube root $\omega = \exp(2 \pi \mathrm{i} / 3)$, but it gets quite ugly.

Comment: The OP wants $a_2$ and $a_3$ to be strictly positive, so you want $z^3/(1-z^3)$, not $1/(1-z^3)$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, thanks for checking. Fixed.